# how to use dynamic base url in component in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

used below code for base url
Configure::write('SITEURL',"http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/mysite url/");

but this is not the correct way to use dynamic base url in cakephp 3, so pls suggest any good answer

Comment: Try this one.You Get your URL Dynamically in cakephp 3   <?php $global_url =   $this->Url->build('/');  echo $global_url;    ?>

Answer (score 1):

```
use Cake\Routing\Router;

$baseurl = Router::url('/', true);
```